# Анимация снизу вверх

Tags: javascript, анимация

Есть такой код

```js
$('.news-block_main').hover(
  function() {
    $('.news-block-hover_main').animate({
      height: "toggle"
    }, 200)('display', 'block');
  },
  function() {
    $('.news-block-hover_main').animate({
      height: "toggle"
    }, 200)('display', 'none');
  }
);
```

```css
.anews {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 33.33%;
}
.news-block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.news-block.news-block_main {
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  border-top: 4px solid #0e0f16;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.news-block-info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 92%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2px 21px 9px;
  color: #fff4e7;
  font-size: .95em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="actuallynews" class="anews">
  <div class="news-block news-block_main " style="background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/h4i1dwG.jpg);">
    <div class="news-block-hover_main" style="display:none;">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/QlPUjPg.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5zpj6oLf/2/

Щас анимация идет сверху-вниз, надо же чтобы снизу-вверх. Как это реализовать?

Comment: было бы неплохо, если бы вы добавили `html` разметку и стили в вопрос

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5zpj6oLf/2/ Держи :)

Comment: Весь код, относящийся к вопросу, должен быть в вопросе, а не на сторонних ресурсах. Пожалуйста, в следующий раз воспользуйтесь сниппетом непосредственно ruSO. Он позволяет это делать ;-)

Comment: А вот эти синие брызги должны все также быть внизу и просто рамка поднимается кверху или как раз таки вверху?

Comment: Ну щас анимация появляется сверху вниз - то есть сначала рамка, а потом брызги, а надо же наоборот снизу вверх - сначала брызги, а потом уже рамка. Просто на брызгах находится текст.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял, достаточно `news-block-hover_main` прилепить к нижней левой части блока и всё.

```
.news-block-hover_main {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height : 100%;
}
```

В данном случае я использовал `0,0`, но судя по `css` это будет немного с другими координатами.

А с нулями пока выглядит так. Но идея, я думаю, понятна. Сделать точку опоры внизу слева.

```js
$('.news-block_main').hover(
  function() {
    $('.news-block-hover_main').animate({
      height: "toggle"
    }, 200)('display', 'block');
  },
  function() {
    $('.news-block-hover_main').animate({
      height: "toggle"
    }, 200)('display', 'none');
  }
);
```

```css
.anews {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 33.33%;
}
.news-block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.news-block.news-block_main {
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  border-top: 4px solid #0e0f16;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.news-block-info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 92%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2px 21px 9px;
  color: #fff4e7;
  font-size: .95em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
.news-block-hover_main {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height : 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="actuallynews" class="anews">
  <div class="news-block news-block_main " style="background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/h4i1dwG.jpg);">
    <div class="news-block-hover_main">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/QlPUjPg.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j3ey11dw/